# how do I diagnose this issue where sshing to another machine causes my display to shut off

Tags: linux, display, xubuntu

Yeah this is weird.

I have an xubuntu 18.04 machine, I have a xfce4 terminal running gnu screen.
In a screen I ssh to this one other xubuntu 18.04 machine, and the ssh connection goes through, but my secondary display shuts off, and my primary displays resolution drops to 1280x1024 or something like that.

Perfectly consistent, every time I ssh to this one machine.

I'd love if somebody had an explanation but I'm sure nobody does. What I'm looking for is how do I even diagnose this.

my .xsession-errors file has this: and that's it.

(xfwm4:6925): xfwm4-WARNING **: 05:19:11.602: output size (1280x1024) and logical screen size (4480x1440) do not match

nothing in syslog or kern.log.

any ideas?

Comment: Which machine -- the client or the server -- has this problem?

Comment: the client, sorry should have mentioned that

Comment: It's all pretty vanilla, nothing in ssh_config or config. yes x11 fowarding is enabled. I'll try not doing that. one moment.

Comment: okay so I disabled X11Forwarding in the server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config and it didn't do it when I sshed, but I think I'm onto something, one sec

Comment: Check if some shell startup script on the remote side tries to interact with the X-server.

Answer (score 1):

I had added a `xrandr -s 1280x1024` command to my profile on the server machine to solve a different problem not realizing the time that sshing to the machine with x11 forwarding on would affect the xserver on the machine I was sshing from.